# Javascript variable in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm currently working on a Chrome extension but I got stuck.. I'm trying to manipulate a textarea with the Chrome extension. If I put in a value directly, the code works fine, but if I want to get the value from a variable it won't work..

This code WORKS:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'document.getElementById("message").value = "Hello!";'
  });
});
```

This code DOESN'T WORK:

```
carName = "Volvo";
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'document.getElementById("message").value = carName;'
  });
});
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong and how I should do it right?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is because that code is executed in the context of the page where `carName` isn't defined. Instead of including the var name in the string, append the var value to the string like so:

```
carName = "Volvo";
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'document.getElementById("message").value = '+carName+';'
  });
});
```

Comment: Also tried that, but it didn't work.. I think it has something to do with the executeScript function, is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

What about defining the variable inside the listener:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  carName = "Volvo";
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'document.getElementById("message").value = carName;'
  });
});
```